# How to call an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, async-await

I want the console to print '1' first, but I am not sure how to call async functions and wait for its execution before going to the next line of code.

```js
const request = require("request");

async function getHtml() {
  await request("https://google.com/", function (error, response, body) {
    console.log("1");
  });
}

getHtml();
console.log("2");
```

Of course, the output I'm getting is

```
2
1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482972/how-to-call-methods-one-after-one/63483268#63483268

Answer (score 106, accepted):

according to [async_function MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> **Return value**
>
> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the async function.

async function will always return a promise and you have to use `.then()` or `await` to access its value

```js
async function getHtml() {
  const request = await $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')  
  return request
}

getHtml()
  .then((data) => { console.log('1')})
  .then(() => { console.log('2')});
  
// OR 

(async() => {
  console.log('1')
  await getHtml()  
  console.log('2')
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

Putting the `async` keyword before a function makes it an asynchronous function. This basically does 2 things to the function:

1. If a function doesn't return a promise the JS engine will wrap this value into a resolved promise. Thus, the function will always return a promise.
2. We can use the `await` keyword inside this function now. The `await` keyword makes it possible to 'wait' for a promise to be settled. Which lets us write asynchronous code in a synchronous way. For example [this tutorial](https://javascript.info/async-await).

In your example the `console.log(2)` will always finish first because in a JS application always the synchronous code will finish first before the asynchronous code. Promises are always asynchronous and thus are `async` fucntions as the name implies also asynchronous. For more on this check out [the event loop.](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Answer (score 10):

You should `await` the async function, if want to wait for it to resolve before continuing or use `.then()`

```
await getHtml();
console.log('2');
```

or

```
getHtml()
 .then(() => {
    console.log('2');
 });
```

Comment: Regarding the first suggestion: Using `await` in the main scope / global scope is a syntax error.

Comment: To circumvent this, you could use a top-level await by changing your Js file ext to .jsm and type='module' in your html script tag

Comment: Thanks for posting the tutorial, that's actually what got me over my particular issue.