# React Validation Async always returning Promise{<pending>}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, react-final-form

So I am doing a basic validation in my React App.  I am using react-final-form and what the validation does it returns an object of errors, if they exists.  For one set of my validation I am using an async function and it always returns `Promise{<pending>}`.  I am not sure why because all my await methods are closed with a `.then()`;  Please have a look at my code:

```
async function checkEmail(email) {
    const result = await axios
            .post(`/api/check-email`, { values: email })
            .then(e => e.data.exists);
            
    return result;
}

// main validation object
const validation: async values => {
        const errors = {};

        if(!values.email) {
            errors.email = "Email is required"
        } else {
            const response = await checkEmail(values.email).then(e => { return e; });
            if(response) {
                errors.email = "Email taken!"
            }
        }

        return errors;
    }
```

Once the email is validated and if the response returns false the validation should return an empty object like `{}` however it returns `Promise {<pending>}`.

Thank you!

Comment: `async` function will always return a `Promise`. It implicitly wraps your `errors` into a `Promise` before returning it.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Thank you so how can i resolve it so instead of a promise I acutally return the object ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982058/how-to-call-an-async-function/49982214#49982214

Comment: @Eddsters Either use `validation(values).then((err)=>..)` or `const errors = await validation(values)` inside another `async` function.

Comment: It is okay to have an async validation function (one which returns a promise) in react-final-form.  Try it! `<Form
      validate={async (values) => {
        const errors = {}
        if(!values.email) {
          errors.email = "Email is required";
        } else {
          const taken = await checkEmail(values.email);
          if(taken) {
              errors.email = "Email taken!"
          }
      }
      return errors;
      }}`