# Render a CSV using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, csv

I'm pretty new to this, and I'm having trouble getting the output I'm looking for. I have a web page where I'd like to display my CSV in a nice looking table. The output is not being displayed on the web page at all when I access the local port. When I go to inspect and then the network tab, I can see that the GET to /data is working. It returns 200, type JSON, and I see the JSON body. Where is the point that's going wrong? Inspect shows JSON returned and logs show 'sending data in res.json' but no 'fetch' (from script.js). Clearly never got there, but why is that and how can I fix it?

script.js:

```js
// Function to fetch CSV data from the server and render it as a table
const fetchAndRenderCSV = async () => {
    try {
        console.log('trying fetch /data')
        const response = await fetch('/data');
        console.log('Response is: ' + response)
        const csvData = await response.json();
        console.log(csvData)
        renderCSVTable(csvData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching CSV data:', error);
    }
};

// Function to render CSV data as a table
const renderCSVTable = (data) => {
    const tableContainer = document.getElementById('csvTableContainer');
    const tableHTML = generateTableHTML(data);
    tableContainer.innerHTML = tableHTML;
};

// Function to generate HTML for the table
const generateTableHTML = (data) => {
    let tableHTML = '<table>';
    // Assuming the first row contains headers
    tableHTML += '<tr>';
    for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        tableHTML += `<th>${data[0][i]}</th>`;
    }
    tableHTML += '</tr>';

    // Add rows for each data entry (excluding the header row)
    for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        tableHTML += '<tr>';
        for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            tableHTML += `<td>${data[i][j]}</td>`;
        }
        tableHTML += '</tr>';
    }

    tableHTML += '</table>';
    return tableHTML;
};

const submitGuess = async () => {
try {
    // Clear result and error messages
    resultMessage.textContent = '';
    errorMessage.textContent = '';

    const inputValue = userInput.value.trim();
    if (inputValue === '') {
        errorMessage.textContent = 'Please enter a name before submitting.';
        return;
    }

    const response = await fetch('/handleInput', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ userInput: inputValue }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.isCorrect) {
        resultMessage.textContent = 'Correct answer!';
        resultMessage.classList.add('correct-answer');
    } else {
        // Shake animation on incorrect guess
        userInput.classList.add('shake');

        // Remove the 'shake' class after the animation ends
        userInput.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
            userInput.classList.remove('shake');
        });

        resultMessage.textContent = 'Incorrect answer.';
        resultMessage.classList.remove('correct-answer'); // Remove the class if present
    }

    userInput.value = '';
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
}
};

// Call the function to fetch and render CSV data when the page loads
console.log('fetch')
fetchAndRenderCSV();
```

styles.css:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#game {
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

#word {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#guess {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#feedback {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.shake {
  animation: shake 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

index.html

```html
<h1>Guess</h1>

<div id="csvTableContainer"></div>
<!-- This is where the table will be rendered -->

<form id="guessForm">
  <label for="userInput">Enter Guess:</label>
  <input type="text" id="userInput" name="userInput" required>
  <button type="button" onclick="submitGuess()" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>

<button onclick="playAgain()" id="playAgainButton">Play Again</button>

<!-- Result message with inline style for correct answer -->
<p id="resultMessage" style="color: green;"></p>

<!-- Error message -->
<p id="errorMessage" style="color: red;"></p>
```

My server.js:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const Papa = require('papaparse');
// const Parse = require('parse');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let isCorrect = false;
let answer, filePath;

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Read CSV file
        const csvData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');

        // Parse CSV data
        const parsedData = Papa.parse(csvData, { header: true }).data;

        // Send parsed CSV data as JSON
        console.log('sending data in res.json')
        const ret = res.json(parsedData);
        // console.log(ret)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading or parsing CSV file:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
    generateCorrectAnswer();
    console.log('The correct answer is: ', answer)
    console.log('filePath is: ' + filePath)
    checkFileExists(filePath)
    readAndParseCSV(filePath);
});
```

Comment: The only function I assume is responsible for creating the table to be displayed is not shown, while it looks like your problem comes from there...

Comment: fixed that sorry!

Comment: Do you get a result (and can you provide a sample of it) from these lines: `const csvData = await response.json(); console.log(csvData)` ?

Comment: No I don't get a response. It never even logs the 'trying fetch /data'

Comment: Where do you make the call `fetchAndRenderCSV()`?  It's not included in your code. See [mcve].

Comment: My mistake, didn't include it. I call it in script.js. The logging statement 'fetch' never gets executed. I thought that it would be executed first, so am I never reaching script.js at all? How could that be

Comment: You just declare the function without calling it `const fetchAndRenderCSV = async () => {` is (without async) the same as `function fetchAndRenderCSV {`

Comment: I edited the post and added it. But yes I called it and I don't seem to be going in there at all

Comment: Likely answer: [how to call an async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982058/how-to-call-an-async-function)

Comment: Update: The HTML wasn't being generated correctly in generateTableHTML. I still haven't gotten it to work, but at least there's some output on the web page. Currently it's just displaying the output all in 1 column

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you weren't actually calling your `fetchAndRenderCSV()` function. In the below snippet I modified the function a little bit to digest a CSV-type input (instead of the pre-processed JSON) and at the end of the snippet I *actually* call the rendering function:

```js
// Function to fetch CSV data from the server and render it as a table
const fetchAndRenderCSV = async () => {
    try {
        console.log('trying fetch /data')
        const csvText = await fetch('https://support.staffbase.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/360009197031').then(r=>r.text());
        let csvData = Papa.parse(csvText,{header:false,skipEmptyLines:true}).data;
        renderCSVTable(csvData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching CSV data:', error);
    }
};

// Function to render CSV data as a table
const renderCSVTable = (data) => {
    const tableContainer = document.getElementById('csvTableContainer');
    const tableHTML = generateTableHTML(data);
    tableContainer.innerHTML = tableHTML;
};

// Function to generate HTML for the table
const generateTableHTML = (data) => {
    let tableHTML = '<table>';
    // Assuming the first row contains headers
    tableHTML += '<tr>';
    for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        tableHTML += `<th>${data[0][i]}</th>`;
    }
    tableHTML += '</tr>';

    // Add rows for each data entry (excluding the header row)
    for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        tableHTML += '<tr>';
        for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            tableHTML += `<td>${data[i][j]}</td>`;
        }
        tableHTML += '</tr>';
    }
    tableHTML += '</table>';
    return tableHTML;
};

fetchAndRenderCSV();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#game {
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

#word {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#guess {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#feedback {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.shake {
  animation: shake 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.4.1/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<h1>Guess</h1>

<div id="csvTableContainer"></div>
<!-- This is where the table will be rendered -->

<form id="guessForm">
  <label for="userInput">Enter Guess:</label>
  <input type="text" id="userInput" name="userInput" required>
  <button type="button" onclick="submitGuess()" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>

<button onclick="playAgain()" id="playAgainButton">Play Again</button>

<!-- Result message with inline style for correct answer -->
<p id="resultMessage" style="color: green;"></p>

<!-- Error message -->
<p id="errorMessage" style="color: red;"></p>
```

I also modified the fetch-URL in order to have a workable snippet here in SO.

Comment: I tried this and the result seems to be pretty much the same. The web page doesn't display and CSV/table data. The inspect > network tab shows GET to https://support.staffbase.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/360009197031 returned 200. Type was CSV in this case instead of mine where it said JSON. Problem is, it still doesn't show on the web page

Comment: Hmm, somewhere on your page you must be doing something different. The above snippet _does_ work. 

Comment: Ya I'm not sure. For this example, where is submitGuess() and the /data? I don't think I understand how all the pieces here are connected

Comment: The way SO works is that you present a problem in the form of an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This way way every question (with their answers) serves as a lesson to other people having similar problems. SO is _not_ a place where you can expect a quality check for your complete web page.

Answer (score -1):

You certainly need to include `submitGuess()` to fire off the whole process.

You should create smaller reduced cases for the best answers.

You may find constructing DOM nodes easier with methods like:

- [parser.parseFromString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)
- [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [insertAdjascentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
const apiEndpoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
const tableContainer = document.getElementById('csvTableContainer');
const parser = new DOMParser();

const submitGuess = () => {
  fetchAndRenderCSV();
};

const playAgain = () => {
  tableContainer.querySelector("table").remove();
};

const fetchAndRenderCSV = async () => {

    const response = await fetch(apiEndpoint);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    renderTable(jsonData);

};

const renderTable = (jsonData) => {

    // create the DOM node
    const table = parser.parseFromString(`<table>
      <thead>
        <th>username</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>website</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>`, "text/html");
    
    // a reference to where rows should be inserted
    const insertionPoint = table.body.firstChild.querySelector("tbody");
   
    jsonData.forEach(user => {
       
       // construct row from data
       const row = `<tr>
           <td>${user.username}</td>
           <td>${user.email}</td>
           <td>${user.website}</td>
       </tr>
       `;
      
       // inject row into table
       insertionPoint.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", row);       
       
    });
      
    // now inject the entire table into page
    tableContainer.append(table.body.firstChild);

};
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

thead {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="submitGuess()" id="submitButton">fetch and render</button>
<button type="reset" onclick="playAgain()" id="playAgainButton">reset</button>

<div id="csvTableContainer"></div>
```